# Linq does not read boolean correctly

Tags: c#, database, linq, boolean

`int propertyCount = PropertyHandler.PropertyList.Count(x => x.Owner == charData.CharacterData.CharacterID && !x.IsRegistered);`

This line checks how much properties link with the owner's ID. I know that the owner owns 3 properties. The second part of the Linq function checks if the property is registered. The owner has 2 registered properties, and 1 unregistered. This means that it should return a value of 1, but no matter which type of code I try, it always returns 3.

I have tried the following functions:

```
int propertyCount = PropertyHandler.PropertyList.Count(x => x.Owner == senderdata.CharacterData.CharacterID && x.IsRegistered == false);

int propertyCount = PropertyHandler.PropertyList.Where(x => x.Owner == senderdata.CharacterData.CharacterID && x.IsRegistered == false).Count();

int propertyCount = PropertyHandler.PropertyList.Where(x => x.Owner == senderdata.CharacterData.CharacterID).Where(x => x.IsRegistered == false).Count();
```

I have also tried without the `== false` part in each function. It always returns 3 even though it should be 1.

```
[Column("IsRegistered")]
public bool IsRegistered { get; set; }
```

This is my database column for `IsRegistered`:

[image: Database Structure]

It shows the structure for that column, which is a `tinyint`.  I don't know what else I can try. I need it to return the correct value (1) instead of 3.

Answer (score 1):

`IsRegistered` is `tinyint` in your database. [According to Microsoft, mapping it to `bool` does not work](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/32639511-1bf2-4863-93d8-e0d217a15b7a/how-to-map-a-tinyint-column-to-boolean?forum=adodotnetentityframework).

You can fix this in one of two ways:

- Change the type to `bit` in the database. This is the type in SQL Server that maps to `bool` of C#.
- Map it to `byte`, and compare to `1` or `0`. Use this approach only if you have no flexibility to change the column type in the database.

Reference: [EF type mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/sql-clr-type-mapping).